# Transformar string em JSONArray erro

Tags: android, json

Estou com essa string para transformar em `JSONArray`. `strbuffer` recebe a string.

```
String strbuffer = stringBuffer.toString();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(strbuffer);
```

Está dando esse erro:

> org.json.JSONException: Value {"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjb2RfdXN1YXJpbyI6IjIiLCJjYWRhc3Ryb191c3VhcmlvIjoic3RlbmlvYmFycm9zb0BnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.PbzD8u3XPQUhD25uc7a8fnEbZdOI4Ep_Y8R6HnKmzVI"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
>
> {"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjb2RfdXN1YXJpbyI6IjIiLCJjYWRhc3Ryb191c3VhcmlvIjoic3RlbmlvYmFycm9zb0BnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.PbzD8u3XPQUhD25uc7a8fnEbZdOI4Ep_Y8R6HnKmzVI"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe JSONArray espera um objeto string em um formato válido de array.

A classe espera uma string no formato: `[{},{},{}]`

Nesse caso a classe correta seria `JSONObject`, ou corrigir o formato da string antes de criar o `JSONArray`.

> {"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjb2RfdXN1YXJpbyI6IjIiLCJjYWRhc3Ryb191c3VhcmlvIjoic3RlbmlvYmFycm9zb0BnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.PbzD8u3XPQUhD25uc7a8fnEbZdOI4Ep_Y8R6HnKmzVI"}"

```
String strbuffer = stringBuffer.toString();
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(strbuffer);
```

Ou:

> [{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjb2RfdXN1YXJpbyI6IjIiLCJjYWRhc3Ryb191c3VhcmlvIjoic3RlbmlvYmFycm9zb0BnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.PbzD8u3XPQUhD25uc7a8fnEbZdOI4Ep_Y8R6HnKmzVI"]

```
String strbuffer = stringBuffer.toString();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(strbuffer);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado entendi.